# Leaf spring preparation

Tags: 4wd, springs, rover, vintage

I have a 1973 series 3 landrover, and have been fortunate to pick up some replacement leaf springs with much less wear than my existing set.

The vehicle is moderately stock, but has a 6 cylinder holden motor (like a 60's GM straight six) which is about 250kg, so ~50kg heavier than the original 2.25 engine at 204kg.

What pre-work can I do before fitting to vehicle to extend their life and keep them running well?  I'm interested in actual experience.

The spring bushes are shot so they will be replaced, as will the U bolts.

- Do I get the springs re-tensioned commercially?
- Is there any lubrication I should work in between the leaves while there is no load on?
- Is it worth painting the springs - if so with what?

The current springs could well be original, I'd like the new set to last as long.

[image]
Springs after a pressure wash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beyond what @cory says, once you get them hung on the chassis and the weight of the diff dangelling on them, the leaves will open up and you can squirt in some marine-grade grease.  This will let the leaves rub against each other smoother.

If you intend on disassembling the spring pack, then you can fit some PTFE-based plastic sheets between each leaf for even more slide.

Downside, this may highlight that your shocks/dampers need replacing too.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably replace the bushings, knock off some of the surface rust, spray a rust inhibitor / paint and put them on. Having them retensioned would be needed if they have flattened out, or your vehicle's extra weight causes the ride height to be too low. No real way of knowing that until you fit them.